# How is android.app->AlertDialog->SetNeutralButton used in fsharp

Tags: android, xamarin, f#, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to convert

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/

to fsharp in Xamarin on a mac, and I'm having trouble guessing the right form of the arguments for SetNeutralButton and similar functions. E.g., even something as simple as

```
[...]
let callDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
[...]
callDialog.SetNeutralButton("Some text", fun (s,e) -> ())
[...]
```

gives type-error in Xamarin [edited]:
[result of mouse-over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyYEi.png)
Can anyone please give or point to an example of the use of these functions in fsharp, that I may learn from?

Thank you, Jon

Comment: You need to post the *specific* error message you're getting, otherwise it will be very hard for anyone to answer your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the translation, @rmunn :-)

Comment: Yes and sorry, mouse-over errors are not available to be easily copied as text. A screen capture has been added to the original question.

Comment: @jon Build the project and copy the build output here

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not very informative: "/Users/sporring/Projects/fsharpTest/fsharpTest/MainActivity.fs(13,13): Error FS0041: No overloads match for method 'SetNeutralButton'. The available overloads are shown below (or in the Error List window). (FS0041) (fsharpTest)" (nothing listed). FYI, I've upgraded to beta channel due to a bug in stable.

Comment: Ahh, I think I got it: `callDialog.SetNeutralButton("some text", fun s e -> ()) |> ignore` - a typical fsharp confusion. Than you all for your time.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer, and accept it, since you resolved the issue.